# Syntax error on token "22f", delete this token

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I'm trying to setup an ArrayList of Float, but in eclipse i keep have an error mark
when i try to add something:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.common.base.Objects;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   
public class MyClass extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    
    //[..]
    
    public static ArrayList<Float> vat_values = new ArrayList<Float>();    
    vat_values.add(22f); 
    
    //[..]
    
}
```

doing `vat_values.add(22f);` i get this errors (red underline under the dot and under '22f'):

> Multiple markers at this line:
>
> Syntax error on token "22f", delete this token
>
> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

but if i only type

> vat_values.add();

i get this error (red underline under the word "add"):

> Syntax error on token "add", Identifier expected after this token

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have code just floating around in the class. You might want to put it in a staic initialization block:

```
public static ArrayList<Float> vat_values = new ArrayList<Float>();

static {
    vat_values.add(22f);
}
```

Comment: i saw today this is the best solution: as i have this ArrayList in a hibernate class, i have to define it as final static otherwise it's treated as a table column.. if i use the @Reimeus solution, everytime i reload the page, the value '22f' is added.. so if after 3 times i have 22f,22f,22f. your solution avoid this problem